# How do you pass a hash table to a function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

When passing a hash table to my PowerShell function, it complains that it receives an object.

```powershell
Function ExtendHash(){
  param(
    [hashtable] $source,
    [hashtable] $extender
  )
  ...
}
```

And the caller:

```powershell
$hash1 = @{One = 1; Two = 2}
$hash2 = @{Two = 22; three = 3}
ExtendHash($hash1, $hash2)
```

> Cannot convert the System.Object[] value of type System.Object[] to type System.Collection.Hashtable

So how do I make this work? Suggestions?

Also, am I missing something built-in? I want the same pattern as what JavaScript uses to extend default options (merge and override default values).

Comment: For your hashtables, shouldn't you use a semicolon instead of a comma - ie. @{One = 1, Two = 2} should be @{One = 1; Two = 2}

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do not use parenthesis and commas. This is PowerShell (say, arguments are similar to arguments of commands in CMD). That is, call your function like this:

```
ExtendHash $hash1 $hash2
```

---

In your case expression `($hash1,$hash2)` is an array of two items and you pass this array, one argument, to the function. Such a call fails correctly.

---

If you use `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` then this "common" mistake is caught by PowerShell:

> The function or command was called as if it were a method. Parameters
>   should be separated by spaces. For information about parameters, see
>   the about_Parameters Help topic.

Comment: Does annoy me a little that powershell makes this confusing by having 2 different syntaxes that are direct opposites for similar things, ie `foo.SomeThing(a, b)` and `Some-Thing a b`

Comment: PowerShell is a shell, in the first place. Then it is also a programming language. This order is by design.

Answer (score 8):

(next to [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931344/1915920):)
The caller does not need to store the hashtables in variables and one can then also use this:

```
ExtendHash  -source @{One = 1; Two = 2}  -extender @{Two = 22; three = 3}
```

(`-source` and `-extender` are necessary so the hashtables themselves do not get interpreted as arg-value-pairs by itself for `ExtendHash`)