# PowerShell function that accepts multiple parameters with the same name, but different values

Tags: powershell

```
Function SetPersonAttributes 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$PersonID,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$FirstName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$MiddleName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$LastName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$FullName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$UserLogonName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$EmployeeNumber,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$EmailAddress  
    )

    If ($FirstName)
    {
        $Body = @{
            name = FirstName
                textValue = @{
                    value = $FirstName
                }
            }

        $SetPersonAttributes = id_query -action SetPersonAttributes -PersonID $PersonID -Body $Body
    }

    If ($LastName)
    {

        $Body = @{
            name = LastName
                textValue = @{
                    value = $LastName
                }
            }

        $SetPersonAttributes = id_query -action SetPersonAttributes -PersonID $PersonID -Body $Body
    }



SetPersonAttributes -PersonID "1234" -FirstName "John" -LastName "Doe" -EmployeeID "9876"
```

I'm trying to build a generic script that can be used in many environments. 
Problem with the approach above is that the attribute names aren't necessarily the same in every environment. 
E.g. In one environment it can be “FirstName” and in the other “First Name” 
or “EmployeeNumber” and “EmployeeID”

And for every attribute an IF statement needs to be created. Not very scale-able.

Therefor I’m looking into creating a function that accepts generic parameters.
e.g

```
SetPersonAttributes -PersonID "1234" -AttributeName "FirstName" -Value "John" -AttributeName "Lastname" -Value "Doe" -AttributeName "EmployeeID" -Value "9876"
```

I’m not sure how to start. I’ve been reading about PowerShell splatting, but I’m not sure if this is the right approach.

Anyone that can push me in the right direction or has an example on how to accomplish this?

Thx!

Comment: I think You would want  - instead of passing named parameters  - pass a Hashtable where key is what You call Attribute name and value is value ?
here's how You do it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931043/how-do-you-pass-a-hashtable-to-a-function-in-powershell

Comment: If the set of alternative names is limited use [Parameter Aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878292(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [parameter alias](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/10/11/use-powershell-parameter-attributes-to-avoid-errors/)
Like this:

```
Function Write-Something {
Param(
[Alias("Text","Word","SomeText")]
[String]$Message
)

    Write-Host $Message

}

Write-Something -Word "a"
Write-Something -SomeText "B"
```